# Problem with database design for Hotel Booking

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

I am currently designing (as an assignment for the course at the university) a database for online booking of hotels worldwide and I have stumbled into a problem.

Before describing it, here are the tables of the relational model so far :

**GUEST**
guest_ID varchar PK
email varchar
guest_password varchar
first_name varchar
last_name varchar
mobile_num varchar
member_status varchar
pref_language varchar
pref_currency_code varchar

**HOTEL**
hotel_ID varchar PK
hotel_name varchar
ratings_avg int
phone_num varchar
email varchar
currency_code varchar
street_name varchar
street_num varchar
zip_code varchar
city varchar
country varchar

**ROOM**
room_ID varchar PK
hotel_ID varchar FK to Hotel
room_name varchar
low_season_rate numeric
high_season_rate numeric
max_persons int

**BOOKING**
guest_ID varchar FK to Guest
room_ID varchar FK to Room
check_in date
check_out date
(a combination of the first 4 as PK)
persons_num int

**PAYMENT**
guest_ID varchar FK to Guest
room_ID varchar FK to Room
date_paid timestamp
amount numeric

**EVALUATION**
guest_ID varchar FK to Guest
hotel_ID varchar FK to Hotel
eval_date date
(a combination of the first 3 as PK)
rating int
guest_comment text

I came up with this design thinking as follows:
The guests will book rooms, which belong to hotels, pay for the rooms and then, if they want, after their stay, evaluate the hotel.

So I considered Booking and Payment as relations between the Guest and the Room and the Evaluation as a relation between the Guest and the Hotel.

The problem this design seems to have is that the Payment and Evaluation are completely cut off from the Booking, so their tables can fill even without a preexisting booking having taken place.
 And the way I see it now, a Guest pays for a Stay(=Booking) in a Room and evaluates a Stay(=Booking) in a Hotel, so I am thinking that these tables should refer to the Booking table.

But Booking is a relation, could I form a relation between an entity and another relation? Or is there another solution that I am missing?

I would welcome any thought about the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your Payment and Evaluation are not "cut off" from Booking.  You can make the relation across more than just one join.  Secondly, remember there is an application on top of the database that will enforce some logic, such as not making bookings without a guest and not making guests without a booking.

If for some reason your requirements dictate that you enforce everything strictly in the database with keys, constraints, and triggers you will need to work on your schema a bit.  I have a few suggestions on that below:

I like identity keys on my tables so that the database doesn't have to enforce combo key relations, I do this in the application layer (it gives me more freedom to make unexpected changes to schema and application later on).

You may want to take the rates out of the ROOM table.  If they are updated, they are no longer applicable to previous BOOKINGs for the same hotel and room.

Payment and Evaluation only need a direct relation to a BOOKING.  You can't have either without an actual stay.

imo a unique BOOKING is a HOTEL and ROOM for date range, so BOOKING should have a fk to HOTEL and ROOM.

How you handle GUEST relating to BOOKING is a little tricky.  GUESTs being able to have more than one BOOKING is expected (imo) so you could put a fk to GUEST on BOOKING so that a BOOKING is now unique to a HOTEL, ROOM, GUEST, and date range.

But, if a BOOKING can have more than 1 GUEST, you need to make a relational lookup.  Just GUESTid and BOOKINGid, so you can have a many::many and still relationally connect GUESTs to BOOKINGs

As long as you can make relational connections across all of your tables with joins, they do not need to all be directly related to all of the others.

Comment: "Cut off" was a bad wording, I mean the same with what you say here: "Payment and Evaluation only need a direct relation to a BOOKING. You can't have either without an actual stay." That is what I was thinking too, but BOOKING imo can't be considered as an entity, as it is an action taken by the guest in a room(and a hotel, as you suggest) and as a relationship I can't put another relationship on it. I was thinking that if we consider a booking as an entity, then everything could be considered as an entity. And this is why I'm stuck

Comment: "Booking" a trip is an action.  But "a booking" can be a noun.  Different cultures refer to hotel stays as bookings, performers often have bookings instead of events.  I think you're tripping yourself up over the wording.  You very clearly have a BOOKING defined as entity with recognizable and meaningful elements.